# Recording Xbox controller button presses?

Tags: tools, xbox360, pc, xbox-controller

I would like to generate some sort of log file of xbox gamepad events while playing an existing game on PC, such as Call of Duty.

I am not developing a game necessarily, I just would like a static file of all button presses recorded during a session of gameplay. I am writing an application that will use this data as input.

Can anyone recommend any software tools that could enable me to do this? Thanks in advance.

I have Mac, Windows, and Ubuntu that I can use.